# Processing multiple item purchase with PayPal

Tags: objective-c, ios, paypal

I am integrating PayPal with my application. I was able to process the single item purchase with simple payment method. I am little bit confused which method should I adopt for the following scenario :

Adding multiple items in to the cart. No of each items added to the cart may or may not be more than one. In simple method, I was able to create an object of PayPalPayment and assigning values to the properties of PayPalPayment.

```
PayPalPayment *payment = [[[PayPalPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
payment.recipient = @"s_biz@gmail.com";//@"example-merchant-1@paypal.com";
payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
payment.description = @"Gift Purchase";//@"Teddy Bear";
payment.merchantName = @"Test Merchant";//@"Joe's Bear Emporium";

payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"];

payment.invoiceData = [[[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init] autorelease];
payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"];
payment.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.35"];

payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];
item.totalPrice = payment.subTotal;    
item.name = @"Flower";
[payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];    

[[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
```

When I try to add more item to the payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems, I was getting some alert like "The amount specified for item price, tax and shipping do not add up to total amount".

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the PayPal example and extending it to have multiple line items, make sure you allocate a new `PayPalInvoiceItem *` for each item you add to the `invoiceItems` array.  If you don't put the allocation inside your loop, you'll be overwriting each additional line item and the invoice total won't come out right.  You didn't post the problem code, but I'll bet you have only one

`PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];`

Instead, alloc and init an additional item object for **each** line item in your invoice.

For example, suppose you have a collection of `LineItem` objects you want to put into the PayPal invoice.  Your "pay" method could look something like this:

```
- (void)payViaPayPal {
    PayPal *payPal = [PayPal getPayPalInst];

    payPal.shippingEnabled = TRUE;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[[PayPalPayment alloc] init] autorelease];

    payment.recipient = @"email@example.com";
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
    payment.description = @"Your order of example stuff";
    payment.merchantName = @"Company Name";

    //subtotal of all items, without tax and shipping
    payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber zero];

    payment.invoiceData = [[[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init] autorelease];

    // No shipping or sales tax in this example
    payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    payment.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (LineItem *lineItem in self.lineItems) {
        PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];

        // If we want these items to show up on the PayPal invoice list, uncomment them.
        //
        // item.itemId = @"...";
        // item.itemCount = ...;
        // item.itemPrice = ...;

        item.name = lineItem.productTypeId.title;
        item.totalPrice = [lineItem.price
                           decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[
                                                         NSDecimalNumber
                                                         decimalNumberWithDecimal:[lineItem.quantity decimalValue]]];
        payment.subTotal = [payment.subTotal decimalNumberByAdding:item.totalPrice];

        [payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];
    }

    [payPal checkoutWithPayment:payment];
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you very much for your information. I hope the issue you mentioned is right. I will let you know after updating the code as you mentioned here.